# Can't configure letsencrypt on nextcloud in docker

Tags: docker, certbot, owncloud

On Linux Mint 21, on my own hardware, I've:

1. installed docker & docker desktop.
2. created an image & container for owncloud that is working.
3. created a maridaDB image & container that's working.
4. configured owncloud to work with mariadb successfully.
5. can successfully access my owncloud instance over the internet on port 80.
6. Stopped Apache on the host since the docker image doesn't need it and Apache was using port 80.

I'm looking for someone that knows how to configure LetsEncrypt with owncloud running in docker on their own hardware. <-- Specifically that setup.

I've watched dozens of YouTube videos and have been to dozens of websites, blogs, & Q&As and not a single one of them gives instructions for installing LetsEncrypt's certbot in a docker container for owncloud on your own hardwar.  None of the instructions I've found work.

I've tried more things than anyone would care to read through.  Here's one, just as an example that doesn't work, but is probably the closest thing to my setup, but it's on a hosted environment and mine's running on my own hardware:

Starting at 3:40 into the video...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0mS1z8Hmhw

```bash
sudo nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt
```

This doesn't work either on the host nor in the terminal in the container (no one ever explains whether to execute these commands on the host or in the container's terminal, BTW).  Earlier in the video, whatever docker image he's using, he says it comes with lets-encrypt already in it.  The official owncloud docker image does not and I'm using the official owncloud docker image.

When I run it on the host, I get:

```bash
sudp: nextcloud.enable-https: command not found
```

When I run it in the owncloud docker image's terminal, I get:

```bash
/bin/sh: 9: sudo: not found
```

When I run it in the owncloud docker image's terminal WITHOUT sudo, I get:

```bash
/bin/sh: 11: nextcloud.enable-https: not found
```

I've been at this for 3 weeks (mostly on the weekends) and am making no progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I *FINALLY* figured it all out and got EVERYTHING up and running.  I'm writing up docs which I'll share here when I'm done.  In the meantime, here are answers to the bigger questions:

### Big Picture of how the completed system will function:

1. User/Client goes to yourdomain.whatever
2. Your web server on your HOST (*NOT* Docker!) receives the request request on port 80 or 443.

   1. Handles the SSL cert, redirects to port 443.
   2. Host web server acts as a proxy to the OwnCloud container in docker running on another port.
   3. OwnCloud communicates with MariaDB container in docker and responds.

### Big Picture of setup process:

1. Install Docker.
2. Create OwnCloud Docker Image.
3. Create MariaDB Docker Image.
4. Configure MariaDB credentials.
5. Configure OwnCloud to connect to MariaDB.
6. Create OnlyOffice Docker image.
7. Configure OwnCloud to use OnlyOffice.
8. Configure web server (Apache) on HOST to act as a reverse proxy for OwnCloud.
9. Install certbot (LetsEncrypt's program) on HOST which modifies Host's Apache config to secure your OwnCloud.